# Opening files from folders in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm a beginning Java programmer and I had a project on my USB and I was trying to double click the source code just from the folder and not going into any software or IDEs.

However, it just opens the code in a Notepad and gives me an "Open with Visual Studio" option when I right click on the folder. There is no "Open with IntelliJ IDEA" option. Would be great if you guys could help me out.

I was also wondering how I could save projects in another folder or drive without having to go to the files program and copying and pasting into the drive I want it to be in.

Comment: You can open a feature request yourself for "open folder as project", but Stackoverflow isn't the right place to do that

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114307#comment=27-2125363 -- check this comment on how to do it yourself. And follow that ticket for updates in general.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a text file and add the following code in it:

```
@echo off

SET PhpStormPath=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.3.1\bin\phpstorm64.exe
 
echo Adding file entries
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\PhpStorm" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open in PhpStorm"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\PhpStorm" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%PhpStormPath%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\PhpStorm\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%PhpStormPath% \"%%1\"" /f
 
echo Adding within a folder entries
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PhpStorm" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with PhpStorm"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PhpStorm" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%PhpStormPath%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PhpStorm\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%PhpStormPath% \"%%V\"" /f

echo Adding folder entries
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PhpStorm" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "Open with PhpStorm"   /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PhpStorm" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /v "Icon" /d "%PhpStormPath%,0" /f
@reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PhpStorm\command" /t REG_SZ /v "" /d "%PhpStormPath% \"%%1\"" /f

pause
```

2. Rename the file with the extension to script.cmd or script.bat
3. Run this file as administrator.

Answer (score 3):

> However, it just opens the code on a notepad and gives me an open with visual studio option when I right click on the folder. There is no "open with Intellij idea" option

Sounds like you're on Windows and missed the option during Intellij installation to associate file types to the IDE.

In windows control center, there is file associations you can edit away from notepad or  you can right click, go to properties, then change the "open with" options

Regarding opening whole folders, I don't typically go through right click menus, but if you want to edit code, you'd typically open the IDE anyway, so just open it, then open the folder as a project

For copying files, I don't quite understand the problem, but it's not going to be solved by Java or Intellij, and I don't know any easier way to copy files between directories or drives

Comment: 1°) You can
2°) It's now the default when you install IntelliJ.
3°) You didn't answer the question

Comment: @Tow This answer is almost 3 years old, and there was no actual question

Answer (score 2):

When you 1st installed IntelliJ, you must have not checked the appropriate boxes to allow you to do those actions that you wanted.  [Installation Options when installing IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFi6A.png)

Under "Update context menu" you should check the box to Add "Open Folder as Project".  This will allow you to choose your directory with all your Java files.

Under "Create Associations" you should check the box for .java.  This will allow to double-click on your .java file to open IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Press ***W+R*** then type ***regedit*** and navigate to the displayed location. If those directories are not there then you can add them and add the value of the icon according to your software location.and then add these to ***command***
[image]